# Sql query to convert or display bytes columns into MB?

Tags: sql, syntax

I have a query as

```
select 
   sourceIP, SUM(sourceBytes) 
from 
   flows 
where 
   sourceBytes > 1000000 
group by 
   sourceIP
```

This query would bring the IP addresses that sent more than 1 million bytes within all flows in a specific time frame, you must enter

The result is similar to

```
------------------------------------
| sourceIP       | SUM_sourceBytes |
------------------------------------
| 64.124.201.151 |   4282590.0     |
| 10.105.2.10    |   4902509.0     |
| 10.103.70.243  |   2802715.0     |
| 10.103.77.143  |   3313370.0     |
| 10.105.32.29   |   2467183.0     |
| 10.105.96.148  |   8325356.0     |
| 10.103.73.206  |   1629768.0     |
------------------------------------
```

I want the sourcebytes to appear as MB format. Do I need a nested query for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this expression. CONCAT is SQL Server 2012+ and deals with datatypes

```
 ...CONCAT(SUM(sourceBytes) / 1048576.0, 'MB')..
```

Example:

```
SELECT
    sourceIP, CONCAT(SUM(sourceBytes) / 1048576.0, 'MB')
FROM
    (VALUES ('10.105.2.10', 4902509.0), ('10.103.70.243', 2802715.0))
    AS flows (sourceIP, sourceBytes)
WHERE 
    sourceBytes > 1000000
GROUP BY
    sourceIP;
```

Otherwise, what is the expected output you want>

Comment: Thanks for help. The from clause with values do I really need it considering I'm using flows (a table)?

Comment: I'm getting error in terms of Exception in query:
line 1:24: unexpected token: (

Comment: Also i'm not using sql server.

Comment: @user3066819: the from clause here is to substitute a table for demo purposes. What engine are you using anyway? It matters for the solution...

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/ajax/download/746eb569-7a71-4c86-94d2-2782fb45713b/e3d25c12-076a-44bb-b8f0-77c938ea7b5f/Ariel_Query_Language_(AQL)_7.2.2.pdf